# Verifying the given answer does not work

Tags: functions, proof-verification, functional-equations

> $y=f(x)$, where $f$ satisfies the relation $$f(x+y)=2f(x)+xf(y)+y\sqrt{f(x)}\text{ }\forall x,y\in R$$
>   If $f'(0)=0$, then $f(6)=?$

The answer given to this question in my textbook ([link](https://www.cengage.co.in/category/test-prep/jee-advanced/mathematics/course/mathematics-for-joint-entrance-examination-jee-advanced-calculus-y1)) is $f(x)=x^2/4$. However, I tried verifying it and it does not seem to be correct. Here's my attempt:

$$\text{LHS}=f(x+y)=(x+y)^2/4=x^2/4+y^2/4+xy/2$$

$$\text{RHS}=2f(x)+xf(y)+y\sqrt{f(x)}\\=2\cdot(x^2/4)+xy^2/4+y\sqrt{x^2/4}\\=x^2/2+xy^2/4+xy/2$$

If we equate $\text{LHS}=\text{RHS}$, which obviously should be true, then $x^2/4+y^2/4=x^2/2+xy^2/4+xy/2$, which is clearly not true.

> What mistake am I making in verifying the answer given in my textbook?

**EDIT:** I have not done the substitution $y=f(x)$, and I can't understand what some commenters below are trying to direct me to.

Comment: You are overloading $y$, od is $f(y)=f(f(x))$?

Comment: So.... $f(x + y) = f(x + f(x))$?

Comment: How do you know $\frac {x^2}4 + \frac {y^2}4 \ne \frac {x^2}2 + \frac {xy^2}4 + \frac {xy}2$?  $y$ is a specific, not arbitrary, function of $x$ with a specific and unusual property.  There is no reason this is "clearly" not so.

Comment: @fleablood But according to the answer given in OP's book, that specific answer is $y=f(x)=x^2/4$. Which doesn't actually satisfy this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they did : they took derivative of the functional equation w.r.t. $x$, put $y=0$, and then solve the differential equation thus generated in $x$.

$$f'(x)=\sqrt {f(x)} \implies \int \frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)}} {\rm d} x=\int {\rm d} x \implies f(x)=\frac{x^2}4$$

What they missed is, they can't just bring $\sqrt{f(x)}$ down to denominator on LHS without considering the case $f(x)=0$. So they missed the original, correct solution, right there in that step.

So how come we're getting $f(x) = x^2/4$ at all?

Well, because this isn't solution of the original functional equation, but it solution of **the obtained** differential equation in $x$, which must have missed some expression containing $y$ only. Since while original functional equation was differentiated, it was treated as constant and it was treated just like it was never there!

This is just like the way we solve trignometric equations. If we square somewhere, we may possibly generate extra root. If we take square root, we may miss a root. Here, forming DEs is equivalent to squaring. If we get exactly what we need, no problem! But if we get an extra root, we need not to be surprised.

Comment: Re: "So they missed the original, correct solution, right there in that step." (+1) for that excellent observation. But, I don't see the point of your second paragraph. Re:"Well, because this isn't solution of the original functional equation, but it solution of the obtained differential equation in x, which must have missed some expression containing y only. " But calculus is filled with examples of such functional equations, where you have to keep one variable constant, and differentiate with respect to the other. Do you mean to suggest that all solutions so obtained are wrong?

Comment: @GaurangTandon There are plenty of other examples too, where forming the differential equation, and integrating again, results in incorrect solution. (Previous AIEEE questions, many were bonuses because two methods yielded different answers). So yes, it is our luck, that most of the times, we don't get any "extra" function as a solution. (We'll always get the correct solution, if we take care of not missing any, at every step)

Comment: You mean to suggest that such a method (of keeping $x$ or $y$ constant, and then differentiating) may yield an "extra" (incorrect) answer if we are not careful. Otherwise, the method is correct and can certainly be used. Am I correctly interpreting?

Comment: @GaurangTandon No, I mean to say that such a method yield an extra incorrect answer **even if we're careful** while solving. We need to be extra careful to **check** whether this obtained function satisfies the given functional equation. But note that we will **never miss correct answer** if we're careful.

Comment: Perfect bro I'll keep this in mind from now, I'm kinda amazed my whole life of calculus and functional equations was a complete lie, and at least I know now that even Cengage can make mistakes ^_^

Comment: @GaurangTandon This is just like the way we used to solve trignometric equations. If we square somewhere, we may possible generate extra root. If we take square root, we may miss a root. Here, forming DEs is equivalent to squaring. If we get exactly what we need, no problem! But if we get an extra root, we need not to be surprised. :)

Comment: Your last comment is very reasonable, and makes the picture complete. Do consider adding it to your original answer.

Comment: Sure brother! ${}$

Answer (score 1):

For $y=0$ we obtain $$f(x)=-xf(0),$$ but $x=y=0$ gives $f(0)=0$, which says $f(x)=0$ and $f(6)=0.$

Comment: I'm getting $f(x)=-xf(0)$?

Comment: I'm not sure how you actually answered my question :/ Do you mean to suggest that the given answer ($f(x)=x^2/4$) is wrong?

Comment: I proved that the answer is $f(x)=0$ and that the answer $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{4}$ is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks, I understood it.